# Buscar Binaria e Ordenação

Tags: c

Tem algum jeito mais eficiente para fazer essa mesma função e não sei pq no meu computador não esta funcionando o codigo.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


void ordena(int A[],int n);
int buscaBinaria( int chave, int inicial, int v[]);

int main ()
{
    /*declaracao das variaveis*/
    int i = 0;
    int A[5];

    /*populaciona o vetor*/
   A[0]= 5;
   A[1]= 4;
   A[2]= 3;
   A[3]= 2;
   A[4]= 1;

    /*imprime o vetor*/
    for (i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {

        printf( " O VETOR DESORDENADO EH DESTA FORMA: %d \n \n", A[i]);
    }
    /*chama a funcao que ordena*/
    ordena(A,5);
    /*imprime o vetor ordenado*/
    for (i = 0; i <5; i++)
    {

        printf( " O VETOR ORDENADO EH DESTA FORMA: %d \n \n", A[i]);
    }
}
void ordena ( int A[],int n)
{

    int j, i;
    /*percorreo vetor*/
    for(j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
      int chave = A[j];


      int m = buscaBinaria(n, chave, A);
      A[j] = A[m];
      A[m] = chave;
    }
}


/* A função abaixo recebe um número x e um vetor
 crescente v[0..n-1]. Ela devolve um índice m
 tal que v[m] == x ou devolve -1 se tal m não
 existe.
 */

int buscaBinaria( int tam, int chave, int v[])
{
   int ini, fim, m, i;
   ini = 0;
   fim = tam - 1;

   while (ini <= fim)
   {
     m = (ini + fim)/2;

     if (v[m] >= chave){
         fim = m - 1;
     }else
         ini = m + 1;
   }
   i = v[m];

   printf("i vale: %d\n", i);

   return m;

}
```

Comment: A busca binária só funciona se o array já estiver ordenado. Logo, não dá para usá-la para ordenar o array, ao menos não do jeito que você está tentando fazer.

Comment: ai eu estou usando a busca binaria  dividir e buscar o menor valor, ai .

Comment: Você está tentando implementar o algoritmo quicksort? Se não, então qual é o algoritmo de ordenação que você está tentando implementar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matheus, não executei seu código, mas pode ser que o fato de estar usando a mesma variável "m" entre as rotinas seja o motivo do erro.